# Get Mysql query file execution result saved in a file using windows CMD

Tags: mysql

I need to get the result of mysql query execution results saved into a txt file. 
The file contains over 600000 lines of insert statements.
The command that I used is:

> mysql -h10.100.109.123 -f -uUserName -pPassword
>   --database=databaseName  < AFC.sql > abc.txt

Abc.txt gets created but there is no data in it. From console, I can see there are many errors. -f is used so that it wont stop on error.

Have gone through and tried out many suggestions of similar question. But none of them worked.
MySql version 5.7

Comment: For starters, have you tried running that SQL script directly on MySQL Workbench?  What are the errors?  Your current observation is completely consistent with a broken script, which therefore did not write anything to the output file.

Comment: Not workbench, used sqlyog which crashed after a while. There are lot of duplicate statements. There are few data too long errors too. I wanted to identify the statements throwing errors other than duplicate and work on it.